# systemd does not rename the interface of my USB wifi adapter after replug

Tags: systemd, udev, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I have a WiFi adapter [ASUS USB-AC53 Nano](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-AC53-Nano/) with rtl88x2bu driver compiled by myself. When I boot my computer, because of the feature [predictable interface names](https://systemd.io/PREDICTABLE_INTERFACE_NAMES/) by systemd, I always get an interface name (`wlx` + its MAC address). From time to time, I need to unplug the adapter and plug it back later. But then the interface name changes to `wlan0`. Then my past WiFi passwords are ignored by NetworkManager because it identifies network connections by interface names.

Right after replugging, I found the following line to indicate the failure (detailed syslog below; I replaced the MAC address to `wlxAABBCCDDEEFF`):

```
wlan0: Network interface 'wlan0' is already up, refusing to rename to 'wlxAABBCCDDEEFF'.
```

If I turn off the interface prior to unplugging through `rfkill`, the issue will be gone, i.e., the interface renaming will succeed. But doing this every time the interface disconnects is super annoying. A WiFi adapter is expected to be hot-pluggable, and I don't want to disable the interface renaming trigger.

So my problem is, can instruct systemd so that the interface renaming work is done before restoring rfkill state? Or can I make a script so that the adapter usable each time I plug it back?

Here is excerpted lines from my syslog. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

```
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop kernel: [416632.769664] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 15
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop dhcpcd[101874]: wlan0: removing interface
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749155.8863] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749155.8906] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749155.9023] radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/ieee80211/phy4/rfkill4 disappeared
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop wpa_supplicant[881]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop wpa_supplicant[881]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop wpa_supplicant[881]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Oct 14 20:05:55 qbane-pop kernel: [416632.837039] rtl88x2bu 1-9:1.0: Runtime PM usage count underflow!
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop kernel: [416633.108966] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop kernel: [416633.257416] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=184c, bcdDevice= 2.10
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop kernel: [416633.257431] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop kernel: [416633.257439] usb 1-9: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop kernel: [416633.257444] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Realtek
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop kernel: [416633.257449] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: 123456
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749156.5956] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749156.5964] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/18)
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9"
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 16 was not an MTP device
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop systemd-udevd[1127599]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
Oct 14 20:05:56 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749156.6197] rfkill5: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/ieee80211/phy5/rfkill5) (driver rtl88x2bu)
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop kernel: [416634.154843] start_addr=(0x20000), end_addr=(0x40000), buffer_size=(0x20000), smp_number_max=(16384)
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop dhcpcd[101874]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop systemd-udevd[1127599]: wlan0: Network interface 'wlan0' is already up, refusing to rename to 'wlxAABBCCDDEEFF'.
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.2909] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9"
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 16 was not an MTP device
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.3798] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.3799] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlan0 created
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.3801] manager: (p2p-dev-wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/19)
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.3802] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.3805] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 14 20:05:57 qbane-pop NetworkManager[808]: <info>  [1665749157.3809] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try to use an `udev` rule.

For example you can create an *udev rules file* that directly assigns `NAME=` (e.g. you can create the file a `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-custom-names.rules`). Add to the rules file the following rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan0", NAME="wlxAABBCCDDEEFF"
```

If this solution doesn't work perhaps the matter is in the ordering/position respective to other udev rules.

Remember to reboot the system after modify or try to use the following command to avoid reboot:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

I think that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1744914/how-to-set-the-ethernet-interface-name-in-a-linux-distribution/1744923#1744923) is a useful link to solve your problem.

**This solution works on a custom Linux distribution and unfortunately I can't try it on a Ubuntu distribution.**

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I tried but unfortunately it failed to rename the interface either, because it is triggered after the interface was enabled.

Comment: @Andy I understand  that your context is very different from mine but try to change the ordering/position respect to other udev rule and read what is write in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1744914/how-to-set-the-ethernet-interface-name-in-a-linux-distribution/1744923#1744923).

Comment: @AndyPan [the link](https://superuser.com/questions/1744914/how-to-set-the-ethernet-interface-name-in-a-linux-distribution/1744923?_gl=1*oqvr47*_ga*MTEwNDQwMzA5Ni4xNjY2Mjc0NTM2*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2NjI4MzI5MC4zLjEuMTY2NjI4NDEwOS4wLjAuMA..#1744923) contains an other method to try to solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried moving the rules around without success, but I will keep dissecting the issue.